# How to resolve the ios appium inspector issue?

Tags: ios, appium

1. I have installed appium version 1.3.3.
2. I have launched appium server to inspect an ios app.
3. I have attached the screen shot for reference.
4. I am getting the below mentioned error message.[image]

Comment: It seems app is not available on path which you have specified.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the test app on your simulator with the Xcode, and then running Appium inspector. It would eliminate if issue was caused due to Instrument not being able to communicate with device